# How can I retrieve image and title in php from custom post type plugin of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

How can i get dynamic data of image and title from this following code? I am currently working on this code but unable to retrieve data. I am attaching screenshot of slider where nothing is displaying as well as i am also adding screenshot of demo slider.

my front-page.php:

```
<?php $our_services = get_our_services_list(5); ?>

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="our-services-slider">
             <?php 
             if(!empty($our_services) && count($our_services) > 0){

            for($i=0; $i<count($our_services); $i++)  {
              ?>
             <div class="slider-tile">
                <div class="tile-img">
                  <img src="<?php echo $services_image; ?>" alt="">

                </div>
                <div class="tile-text">
                  <h4>
                    <b><?php echo $post_title; ?></b>
                  </h4>
                  <p><?php echo $post_excerpt; ?></p>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <a class="btn btn-mehroon" href="<?php echo $services_button_link; ?>">
                    <?php echo $services_button; ?></a>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
<?php } }  ?>
```

my functions.php:

```
function get_our_services_list($per_page_record = -1){
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => $per_page_record,
    'orderby'          => 'ID',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'our_services'
);

 return get_posts($args);
}
```

Demo page

[image]

my page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should try this :

```
<?php
        $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'client_testimonial',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'=> 6,
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'date'  
                     );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);                       
        ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

// you can get image like this :

```
<?php  $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

// get title like this:

```
echo get_the_title(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: ok make sure that you are in while loop, and also try this : echo get_the_title($query->ID); or you can also use only :  the_title();

Comment: facing same problem again

Comment: have you used wp_query in any place on that page? please share your whole code along with custom post type detail